# Sharing of Model object across classes

Tags: java, oop, object

I have a model class `Team`. I need to perform multiple operations on this class in different classes like `Coach` and `Admin`. My question is how do I maintain once same `Team` object while creating all other classes.??

In the `TestDriver` class , I have used the team object to create `Coach` initially. But if I want to create new `Admin` ,I need to pass the same `Team`. Is there any pattern I need to follow here.?

```
//Model Classes

public class Player {
    String playerName;
}

public class Team {
    List<Player> playerList;
}


//Class to modify model

public class Coach {
    Team team;

    public Coach ( Team team) {
        this.team = team;
    }

    public void deletePlayer(Player) {
        //Remove the player form team
    }
}

public class Admin {
    Team team;

    public Admin ( Team team) {
        this.team = team;
    }

    public void addPlayer(Player) {
        //Add the player to team
    }
}

//Test Driver class 

public class TestDriver {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Team team = new Team();

        Coach coach = new Coach(team);
        coach.deletePlayer(team);

        //How to pass the same team
        Admin admin = new Admin(???);
        admin.addPlayer(team);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do :`Admin admin = new Admin(team);`

Now both the `admin` and `coach` instance will be referring to the same `team` instance. So whatever changes you make to the `team` in one will reflect in the other.

You should read more about how in Java the variables are only holding the references to actual object in memory.

Answer (score 1):

Use the same object/variable `team`

```
Team team = new Team();

Coach coach = new Coach(team);
coach.deletePlayer(team);

Admin admin = new Admin(team); // <-- here
admin.addPlayer(team);
```